# useEffect const declarations require an initialization value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some code inside of a useEffect hook, and am getting an error in my codesandbox saying const declarations require an initialization value.

I understand most times this means there is code following a return statement, but that's not the case here. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Any help appreciated. Link to sandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/fee-hn-job-board-v4lnk?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Include relevant code within the question. Voted to close as it is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a closing-curly bracket on line 19. Since it's missing, it's not executing the rest of the useEffect hooks callback.